# Change playback device "default format" in Windows 7 from command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, audio

How can I change the speaker's default audio format from the command line?

[image: Windows configuration dialog showing the "Default Format" option.]

I have an intermittent audio problem (probably from driver/sound card/motherboard incompatibility) that I can temporarily fix by changing the audio bitrate. Until I can fix this problem, I want to be able to change this option without navigating the configuration GUI.

My current flow for getting to this option is:

1. Right click on speaker tray icon
2. Click "Playback Devices"
3. Double-click on "Speakers"
4. Click the "Advanced" tab
5. Choose an option from the dropdown
6. Click "OK" and apply the change.